# Knapsack variation in Programming contest

Tags: arrays, algorithm, knapsack-problem

Question:

An exam consists of N questions. The marks of the N questions are m1, m2, m3, .. mN respectively.
Jam is giving the exam and he wants to maximise his number of marks.
However he takes some time to solve each question. The time taken by him to solve the questions are t1, t2, t3, .. tN respectively.
The exams lasts for a total of time T.
But Jam's teacher is very smart and she knows that Jam will find out a way to get maximum marks. So, to confuse Jam, she also puts up a bonus offer for him -
The offer is that Jam can select a question for which he can double the marks awarded for that question.
Now, Jam is indeed confused. Help him find out the maximum number of marks he can gain.

Constraints

1<=N<=1000

1<=T<=10000

1<=mi<=100000

1<=ti<=10000

I tried this question [here](http://www.codechef.com/NCC2014/problems/EXAM) and came up with the following algorithm:

Since the problem says, we can select a question for which he can double the marks awarded for that question.

So, for selecting that question I applied Greedy Approach i.e..

1. the question having larger (marks/time) ratio should be selected for which he can double the marks awarded for that question.
2. And if that ratio is also same then the question having larger marks should be selected.

   And the rest is simple knapsack as far as i understood the question.
   I tried the following implementation but got wrong answer.
   for the given test case my code is giving correct output

   3
     10
     1 2 3
     4 3 4

i have tried this test case given in comments section and my code gives 16 as output but answer should be 18

```
  3 
  9
  9 6 5
  8 5 3
```

A brute force approach would give time limit exceeded as solving N knapsacks eack of complexity O(nW) will give overall time complexity of O(n^2 W)
I think that a more concrete algorithm can be developed for this question.
Does anyone have any better idea than this?

Thank you

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdio>
    using namespace std;
    int T[2][10002];
    int a[1000002],b[100002];
    float c[100002];
    int knapSack(int W,int val[],int wgt[],int n)
    {
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            for(j=0;j<W+1;j++)
            {
            if(i==0 || j==0)
            T[0][j]=0;
            else if(wgt[i-1]<=j)
            T[0][j]=max(val[i-1]+T[1][j-wgt[i-1]],T[1][j]);
            else
            T[0][j]=T[1][j];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(j=0;j<W+1;j++)
            {
            if(i==0 || j==0)
            T[1][j]=0;
            else if(wgt[i-1]<=j)
            T[1][j]=max(val[i-1]+T[0][j-wgt[i-1]],T[0][j]);
            else
            T[1][j]=T[0][j];
            }
        }
    }
    if(n%2!=0)
        return T[1][W];
    else
        return T[0][W];
    }


    int main()
    {
    int n,i,j,index,t,mintime,maxval;
    float maxr;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>t;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>b[i];

    maxr=0;
    index=0;
    mintime=b[0];
    maxval=a[0];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            c[i]=(float)a[i]/b[i];  
                if(c[i]==maxr && b[i]<=t)
                {
                    if(a[i]>=maxval)
                    {
                    maxval=a[i];
                    mintime=b[i];
                    index=i;
                    }
                }   
                else if(c[i]>maxr && b[i]<=t)
                {
                maxr=c[i];
                maxval=a[i];
                mintime=b[i];
                index=i;
                }

        }

    a[index]=a[index]*2;
    int xx=knapSack(t,a,b,n);
    printf("%d\n",xx);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a greedy approximation when the question requires an exact answer?

Comment: @user2357112:because i could not think of a better approach

Comment: The brute force approach is to solve N knapsacks (in each of them another question is selected for doubling) and take the overall best solution.

Comment: @Henry:thanks for suggesting brute force approach but that would surely give time limit exceeded

Comment: @user2357112: I already know brute-force.Is there better than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve the problem, let's first look at [the wikipedia article on the Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which provides a dynamic programming solution for the regular problem:

```
// Input:
// Values (stored in array v)
// Weights (stored in array w)
// Number of distinct items (n)
// Knapsack capacity (W)
for j from 0 to W do
  m[0, j] := 0
end for 
for i from 1 to n do
  for j from 0 to W do
    if w[i] <= j then
      m[i, j] := max(m[i-1, j], m[i-1, j-w[i]] + v[i])
    else
      m[i, j] := m[i-1, j]
    end if
  end for
end for
```

(And as the article says, you can reduce the memory usage by using a 1-d array m, rather than a 2-d array).

Now we can use this idea to solve the extended problem. You can compute two tables: instead of m, you can compute m0 and m1. m0[i, w] stores the maximum value attained using the first i items with weight (in your case time) at most w, *without using* the double-scoring question. Similarly, m1 stores the maximum value attained using the first i items with weight (in your case time) at most w, and *using* the double-scoring question.

The update rules change to:

```
if w[i] <= j then
    m0[i, j] := max(m0[i-1, j], m0[i-1, j-w[i]] + v[i])
    m1[i, j] := max(m1[i-1, j], m1[i-1, j-w[i]] + v[i], m0[i-1, j-w[i]] + 2 * v[i])
else
    m0[i, j] = m0[i-1, j]
    m1[i, j] = m1[i-1, j]
end if
```

As in the regular problem, you can use two 1-d arrays rather than two 2-d arrays to reduce the memory usage.

Comment: It does not answer the question, this is a variation of knapsack, and not "regular" knapsack

Comment: @amit I don't think you read the full answer. I introduce the solution to the regular problem so I can extend it to the problem with the double-scoring item.

Comment: Yea, you hid it too well. apologies, try formatting it better (the start of the answer, and a large portion of it is to the regular knapsack...) - other than it, nice answer (+1).

Comment: PS, I was thinking about the same thing, but it would be more elegant to use an extra dimension instead of `m0,m1`, IMO.

Comment: Thanks @amit, I've edited the answer to make it clearer why I'm first looking at the regular problem.

Comment: Another possibility is to just sort the items by weight. Then the result is MAX(i=1 to n, 2*v[i] + m0[i-1, W-w[i]). No third dimension needed.

Comment: Sorry I meant sort the items by value there. Because you will always double the value of the highest-value item you take

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use dynamic programming?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming